# Thermodynamic Functions

Tags: thermodynamics

> Indicate the correct statements:
>
> **a**. $\mathrm{d}A = -S\mathrm{d}T$ for an ideal solution undergoing an adiabatic process.
>
> **b**. $\mathrm{d}G = -\mathrm{d}(TS)$ for an ideal solution undergoing an isobaric process.
>
> **c**. $\mathrm{d}A = \mathrm{d}U - T\mathrm{d}S$ for an ideal solution undergoing an isothermal process.

The answer is statements (**a**) and (**b**).

How, though?

$\mathrm{d}A = \mathrm{d}U - \mathrm{d}(TS)$. Since it is adiabatic, $\mathrm{d}q = 0$, or $T\mathrm{d}S = 0$.

So $\mathrm{d}A = -P\mathrm{d}V - S\mathrm{d}T$. What happened to the $-P\mathrm{d}V$ term?

$\mathrm{d}G = \mathrm{d}H - \mathrm{d}(TS)$

$\mathrm{d}G = V\mathrm{d}P - S\mathrm{d}T$, so $\mathrm{d}G = -S\mathrm{d}T$.
Why did they add the $-T\mathrm{d}S$ term?

$A$ is the Helmholtz free energy and $G$ is the Gibbs free energy.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't indicating the incorrect statements? Because c is the only one at a glance I can can see justification for. Can you put a source for where you found this question?